# CodeIgniter DataMapper Error: You must use the "set" method to update an entry

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I'm using codeigniter/datamapper to develop an inviocing application and I'm getting an error that i don't understand. If I do the following:

```
$i = new Invoice();    
$i->save();
```

Then i get the following error:
    A Database Error Occurred

```
You must use the "set" method to update an entry.

Filename: /Users/jim/Sites/example.com/libraries/Datamapper.php

Line Number: 1635
```

However I can run this all day without any problem:

```
$i = new Invoice();    
$i->notes ='x';
$i->save();
```

Just wondered why it behaves like this? Any help/comments much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: In the first example, you are attempting to save a completely empty object to the database. DataMapper assumes that you want the object to have some data in it before being written to the DB and, thus, refuses to store an empty record.

Comment: ah, ok, i thought i might save it with the autoincrement id, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the datamapper you must assign the value to the object. If the object is empty then it is not going to save. So firstly set the value for the datamapper object.